# TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i have recently started to learn react and i wanted to change the App component and this error popped out

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

here's the code : app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p> hello  {this.props.yourName} </p>
      </header>
    </div>
```

and the index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

let yourName="yourName";

ReactDOM.render(
 <App yourName />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: first thing is your app.js is functional component, we do not use "this" in functional component, so remove "this" and make it "props.yourname". Second pass props as an argument in function App(props){ //code }

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other cases in javascript which treating object with same "address" and "context" is in one place, in sending props if you send only

---

```
   <App yourName >
```

---

it comes in { props.yourName == true }, and not with the string value you sent.

change it to

---

```
      <App yourName={yourName}/>
```

---

and remove { this } keyword from { App } which is function and not class

---

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App(props){
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <p> hello  {props.yourName} </p>
    </header>
  </div>
```

---